# how to filter and find inside an object

Tags: javascript

I want to search the finder object inside the branches array and if it finds the match, then I want to get the location name of the finder object.

```
var branches= [
  {
    locationName: "Cool Towers",
    coordinates: [
      {
        latitude: 25.33853805869942,
        longitude: 55.393801012135796,
      },
      {
        latitude: 25.33848836326937,
        longitude: 55.393874772883706,
      },
      {
        latitude: 25.338230189121408,
        longitude: 55.39362935075884,
      }
    ],
  },
  {
    locationName:"Great Towers",
    coordinates: [
      {
        latitude: 25.16626719853835,
        longitude: 55.26170584184425,
      },
      {
        latitude: 25.166607063076132,
        longitude: 55.26206257564323,
      }
    ],
  }
]
```

```
var finder = 
  {
        latitude: 25.166607063076132,
        longitude: 55.26206257564323,
  }
```

This case expected result is : Great Towers

this is what i have tried. But this always giving me the first location name

```
const filter = Object.entries(finder),
  result = branches
    .filter(({ coordinates }) =>
      filt.every(([key, value]) => coordinates[key] === value)
    )
    .map(({ locationName }) => locationName);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will find for the branch that has coordinates equal to `finder`

```js
var branches = [
  {
locationName: "Cool Towers",
coordinates: [
  {
    latitude: 25.33853805869942,
    longitude: 55.393801012135796,
  },
  {
    latitude: 25.33848836326937,
    longitude: 55.393874772883706,
  },
  {
    latitude: 25.338230189121408,
    longitude: 55.39362935075884,
  }
],
  },
  {
locationName:"Great Towers",
coordinates: [
  {
    latitude: 25.16626719853835,
    longitude: 55.26170584184425,
  },
  {
    latitude: 25.166607063076132,
    longitude: 55.26206257564323,
  }
],
  }
];

var finder = {
latitude: 25.166607063076132,
longitude: 55.26206257564323,
}

var branch = branches.find(branch => {
return branch.coordinates.find(coordinate => {
    return coordinate.latitude == finder.latitude && 
           coordinate.longitude == finder.longitude
})
});

console.log(branch.locationName)
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to achieve what you are trying to do:

```
const match = branches.find((branch) => {
  return branch.coordinates.find((coords) => {
    return finder.longitude === coords.longitude && finder.latitude === coords.latitude
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it using [Array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and [Array.findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)

```js
const branches = [
  {
    locationName: "Cool Towers",
    coordinates: [
      {
        latitude: 25.33853805869942,
        longitude: 55.393801012135796,
      },
      {
        latitude: 25.33848836326937,
        longitude: 55.393874772883706,
      },
      {
        latitude: 25.338230189121408,
        longitude: 55.39362935075884,
      }
    ],
  },
  {
    locationName:"Great Towers",
    coordinates: [
      {
        latitude: 25.16626719853835,
        longitude: 55.26170584184425,
      },
      {
        latitude: 25.166607063076132,
        longitude: 55.26206257564323,
      }
    ],
  }
];

const finder = {
  latitude: 25.166607063076132,
  longitude: 55.26206257564323
};

const findCoordinate = (co) => {
  return (co.latitude === finder.latitude) && (co.longitude === finder.longitude);
}

const branch = branches.find((item) => item.coordinates.findIndex(findCoordinate) >= 0);
if (branch) {
  console.log(branch.locationName);
} else {
  // Not found
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
let result;
for(let i = 0; i < branches.length; i++) {
    if (branches[i].coordinates.findIndex(coord => coord.latitude === finder.latitude && coord.longitude === finder.longitude) >= 0 ) {
      result = branches[i].locationName;
      break;
    }  
}
console.log(result);
```

Comment: A snippet could be useful.

Comment: With the for loop you may exit the loop and return results as soon as you find the match, where as with other listed here examples you should go through each iteration step.

Comment: A snippet, not an explanation.